# Strange background color on ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Currently I'm using ActionBarSherlock and custom ListView Adapter, but I have this strange case on my ListView. There's different color at the top of ListView, and Icon background should be transparent, but it has background color. Please take a look at the picture and if you don't mind, enlighten me.

[image: ListView]

[image: Another Activity]

Comment: It's hasn't anything to do with ListView, it looks like come from ActionBarSherlock, and I don't know why :s

Comment: Im going blind. I dont see this extra color, and your icon looks transparent to me.

Comment: If you look closely you will see the difference :D

Comment: I dont think its worth worrying about. I can barely see it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem come with ActionSherlockBar theme, to be precise is Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar. When I set to Theme.Sherlock.Light this problem don't appear. I don't know why.